# Margin / border on jScrollPane hides arrow

Tags: javascript, css, jscrollpane

Using jScrollPane on the vertical scroll I've come to problem. Tried to give a margin / border on the bottom of the arrows or even a margin all around the .jspVerticalBar and it just "hides" my bottom arrow!

Ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to subclass the Painter of your ScrollBar :

Look at this :

http://explodingpixels.wordpress.com/2008/12/08/skinning-a-scroll-bar-part-1/
http://explodingpixels.wordpress.com/2008/12/08/skinning-a-scroll-bar-part-2/

Specially, you'll have to enlarge the bounds, to get some place left for drawing borders around the arrows.

Comment: Doesn't jScrollPane have some function easier to do that? Oh wait... I'm talking of the JavaScript jScrollPane, the plugin